# How do I import svn branches rooted in different directories into git using git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have an SVN repository structure like below. We are using multiple levels under branches for various release maintenance branches, plus a directory for feature branches.

git-svn init seems to work with a single --branches argument, i.e. it seems to expect all of the branches to be in a single location.

```
trunk
branches
  1.1
    1.2.1
    1.2.2
  1.2
    1.2.1
    1.2.2
    1.2.3
  features
    feature1
    feature2
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Probably this has changed since 2008, but nowadays "you can specify more than one ``--tags`` and/or ``--branches`` options, in case your Subversion repository places tags or branches under multiple paths." (quoted from ``man git svn branch``)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your config file, set the svn-remotes section to something like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://svnserver/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

This should let you grab the nested branches.

Comment: This completely solves my problem. I've been using this for a while now. It did require later versions of git and/or svn, sorry I don't know the particulars but am currently using git 1.6.2.5 and svn 1.5.1 and it works fine with that.

Comment: you need to delete `.git/svn/.metadata` and git a `git svn fetch` to refresh the branch/tag list

Comment: What happens if you have branch/a/thisname and branch/b/thisname? Doesn't it explode?

Answer (score 1):

By convention, Subversion branches all live in a single 'branches' path in the Subversion repository, so I'm not surprised that `git-svn` makes this assumption.

I'd suggest the following (note, you may lose some history in this operation):

1. Flatten the Subversion `branches` paths, using a naming convention to keep unique identities and the idea of the current structure.
2. Perform `git-svn`
3. Move things around in the `git` repository to conform with your practices.

The danger of `losing history` depends on how well `git-svn` follows copy operations from dissimilar paths.  I've run into this problem migrating subversion repositories (1.4-ish) recently.

Comment: do you mean flatten svn branches on my computer of on the svn server (which i can't do)?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible to create a `git` repo for each of the branch subdirectories?

Comment: And then, what, merge them all together and create the proper branches/tags after the fact?  There's got to be a simpler solution

Comment: The simplest solution would be to flatten your branches directories into a single directory, which would not only make `git` happy, but also bring your repo in line with the `svn` conventions. I'm not sure how practical that is in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could add multiple `git svn` remotes for each of the branches, or possibly each of the directories of branches.  The initial `git svn fetch` would take forever, but from what I understand it should work.