# how to use nested branches through git-svn

Tags: svn, git, branch, git-svn

our svn server has a trunk called Dev and Branches live in

```
/Branches/Release/1.0/
                 /2.0/
                 /2.3.4/
```

i cloned it with something like `git svn clone -T Dev ... -b Branches ...`
when I run `git branch 2.1 remotes/Release/2.1` i get:
`fatal: Not a valid object name: 'remotes/Release/2.1'.`

- How do I refer to the remote branch?
- Do I need to re-clone with different args?

Comment: I think you're SOL bud :/ You imported one Branch: Release with folders in it.

Comment: How should I fix this for next time i clone?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258590/how-do-i-import-svn-branches-rooted-in-different-directories-into-git-using-git

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How do I import svn branches rooted in different directories into git using git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258590/how-do-i-import-svn-branches-rooted-in-different-directories-into-git-using-git-s)", you need to grab all the nested branch during the initial import:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://svnserver/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

That is also described in [this thread](http://lists-archives.org/git/629402-git-svn-and-a-nested-branches-folder.html).
For even more complex SVN branch layout (like [branches within trunk!](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fixing-branches-from-a-really-messed-up-subversion-repository-td5182691.html)), a modification of the SVN repo might be in order first, before putting in place a git-svn integration.

Since Git1.6, "1.6.x offers deep cloning so that multiple wildcards can be used with the --branches option", as mentioned in "[Cloning a Non-Standard Svn Repository with Git-Svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn)".

```
git svn clone https://svn.myrepos.com/myproject web-self-serve --trunk=trunk --branches=branches/*/* --prefix=svn/
```