# Import separate SVN directories as git branches

Tags: git, svn, import, branch, git-svn

I want to convert an existing SVN repository with a nonstandard layout that looks like this:

```
/ (root)
    /trunk
        regular trunk stuff that I would like to make the "master" branch
    /folder1
        files that I would like to make a separate branch "folder1"
    /folder2
        files that I would like to make a separate branch "folder2"
    /folder3
        files that I would like to make a separate branch "folder3"
```

... to a git repository, preserving history.

The catch is that `folder1`, `folder2`, and `folder3` are not branched off from some point in `trunk`; they are a separate set of files, and they are not rooted in some convenient subdirectory (which is what makes this question differ from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258590/how-do-i-import-svn-branches-rooted-in-different-directories-into-git-using-git)).

The desired git branch layout would look like:

```
master -----+------(trunk r1)------(trunk r2)----...
            |
folder1     \-----(folder1 r1)----(folder1 r2)---...
            |
folder2     \-----(folder2 r1)----(folder2 r2)---...
            |
folder3     \-----(folder3 r1)----(folder3 r2)---...
```

(Those revision numbers aren't actual svn revision numbers, just the number of the commit in that particular folder)

I've tried using `git svn` but it seems to want the branches to be in a single directory, containing one subfolder per branch. The problem is that if I do this, I would have to use `/` (the root directory) as branches directory, which would make `trunk` a separate branch (while I want to use it as the `master` branch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by specifying multiple "trunks" to `git svn` by editing your `.git/config` file.

Initialize your git repository as normal:

```
git svn init {url-to-repository} -T trunk
```

Now if you edit your `.git/config` file, you'll find a section that looks something like the below:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = {url-to-repository}
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
```

Simply add some lines like the below, which will add each folder as a single folder to be fetched (as opposed to a folder of branches or a folder of tags to fetch):

```
    fetch = folder1:refs/remotes/folder1
    fetch = folder2:refs/remotes/folder2
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression you really have four separate repositories that you want to track in a single git repository with each repo on its own branch. Not exactly how git is intended to be used but you can try this configuration setup:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo

git init .
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "Initial repository"

git checkout -b folder1
mkdir folder1
touch folder1/svn-code-here # Add SVN files to folder1
git add folder1
git commit -m "folder1 branch"

git checkout master

git checkout -b folder2
mkdir folder2
touch folder2/svn-code-here # Add SVN files to folder2
git add folder2
git commit -m "folder2 branch"

git checkout master

git checkout -b folder3
mkdir folder3
touch folder3/svn-code-here # Add SVN files to folder3
git add folder3
git commit -m "folder3 branch"

git checkout master
touch svn-trunk-code-here # Add SVN files to trunk
git add svn-trunk-code-here
git commit -m "trunk started"
```

This will create your three folder branches with only the shared README file from the initial *trunk* master created. This will create a branch graph like:

[image: Git Branches]

In the command sequence above, you would replace each `touch svn-code-here` with the commands and steps needed to extract the SVN files to the directory and add/commit to Git. When you checkout master none of the folder directories will be visible and you can use master as your *trunk* and switch branch to the folders as needed `git checkout folder1`.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't think it's possible to import commits from SVN once the Git repository already has some commits in it :( That would effectively require adding commits from the past. That, and `git svn` assumes that it should check things out in the `master` branch, even when I am in the `folderx` branch.

Comment: @EtiennePerot each branch has its own timeline as they will never be merged back together with master, but I would recommend just each folder as a separate repository personally.

Comment: Yes, but they are all branching off from that one first commit in `master` where `README` is added, which means their timeline starts there. Given this, commits cannot be imported from SVN, because the SVN repository doesn't contain such a `README` file (so it doesn't really make sense to continue adding commits to a non-identical-to-the-SVN-repo tree) but also because those commits from SVN are much older (timestamp-wise) than that `README` commit in `master` (which was done just now)

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the svn history? If not, then no special import is needed. My approach was from a fresh history based on svn head.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to preserve all history, that's what makes it tricky. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll edit the question to mention that.