# How to show all folders from Wordpress.org SVN plugin repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, wordpress, git-tower

I have been approved for a repo on the Wordpress.org site for a new plugin I created. I am testing out Tower to see if it will work for me and allow Git as well as SVN version control.

I have created the repo in Tower it shows Master but there are other folders in the WP repo specifically "assets" that I can't seem to get to appear in the app.

Shouldn't this appear as a branch? (I'm new to version control so forgive me if I am unclear or use wrong terminology)

I just assumed that I would see all the branches (assets, tags, trunk, branches) yet all I see is Trunk. This is version one so I expect to see no tags.

I believe I have the SVN directory set up correctly:

```
Trunk: reftagger-shortcode/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
Branches: reftagger-shortcode/branches/*:refs/remotes/*;reftagger-shortcode/assets/*:refs/remotes/*
Tags: reftagger-shortcode/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

And they appear correct in the git/config too.

Here is a link to a [Tower screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/28074n8/8)

Answer (score 1):

The [Wordpress FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/faq/) states:

> Screenshot image files should ideally be put in the `assets/` directory (which you'll likely need to create) in the root of your SVN checkout.
>   This will be on the same level as `tags/` and `trunk/`, for example.
>
> Alternatively, screenshots can be put in the directory of the tagged stable release (`trunk/` or the stable `tag` directory) (the old way).
>
> The `assets/` directory is preferred since the screenshots won't be packaged in the plugin's release zip files, saving unnecessary bloat for each download.

Since:

- SVN folder can be considered branches
- Git only shows you the content of one checked out branch at a time

If you have followed the first option for `assets/` folder, the SVN repo once converted in a Git repo would consider `assets` as a branch (or would ignore it completely, having only converted trunk into a `master` branch).
Note that you can [import separate SVN directories as git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647440/6309), if some of those SVN folders (like `assets/`) are missing.

Hence `asset/` being not visible.

Comment: Thanks for the info @VonC. Since it was a new plugin the repo was already set up with the `assets/` folder. I also used a SVN client originally to add all my files, but I am looking for GIT client to do both hence [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/). You will note my set up above for the directory set up in Tower. It adds the correct code to the `git/config` that reads
`fetch = reftagger-shortcode/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = reftagger-shortcode/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
branches = reftagger-shortcode/assets/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = reftagger-shortcode/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/`